# Accessing java inner classes in struts.xml

Tags: java, xml, struts2, inner-classes

Is it possible to access java inner classes in struts.xml file? For example, I have the following java class with a nested class:

```
public class FooServiceAction {

FooServiceImpl service = new FooServiceImpl();

public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {

    private ProductImpl product = new ProductImpl();

    public ProductAction() {

    }

    public ProductAction(ProductImpl product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public ProductImpl getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(ProductImpl product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String productSetting() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        if (this.getProduct().getName() == null
                || this.getUser().getName().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("name", "Product name is mandatory.");
        } else {
            service.createProduct(product);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to access the nested ProductAction class in struts.xml file.

```
<action name="createProduct" class="foo.action.FooServiceAction.ProductAction" method="productSetting">
        <result name="success">/launchapp.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/createUser.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Whenever I am trying to launch this project with jetty, an exception is thrown because struts.xml cannot locate the nested java class.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.0.1:run (d
>   efault-cli) on project foo-web: Failure: StrutsException: Unable to load configu
>   ration. Action class [foo.action.FooServiceAction.ProductAction] not found -> [Help 1]

How can I make the nested java class visible to struts.xml file?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do not nest action classes. That is *really* bad. Use `extends` to incorporate functionalities and reduce redundancies (DRY)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrea. Is there an explanation why nesting is not good practise for Action classes?

Comment: May I ask you where have you seen nested actions ? Any official documentation, online tutorial, what ? For a successful living, don't create monsters :)

Comment: :D Thanks Andrea, will keep that in mind! I need some functionalities on my action class and I have quite messed it up with nesting it inside another class. Totally forgot about extends... Many thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible if you make an inner class static. See the below code

```
public class FooServiceAction {
  public static class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {
```

Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name:

```
<action name="createProduct" class="foo.action.FooServiceAction.ProductAction" method="productSetting">
```

Struts will create an object for the static nested class using `ObjectFactory` like:

```
foo.action.FooServiceAction.ProductAction action =
     new foo.action.FooServiceAction.ProductAction();
```